# Пунктуация при однородных определениях

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-неоднородные-определения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в первом случае не нужна запятая, а во втором нужна?

> 1. Принесли теплые густые сливки.
> 2. Теплый, густой запах смолы наполнял воздух.

Ведь в обоих вариантах определения качественные и однородные.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. ***Принесли теплые густые сливки.***

В этом предложении определения **неоднородны**, они описывают разные признаки определяемого слова: ***теплые*** — температуру, ***густые*** — консистенцию.

[**Однородные и неоднородные определения**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98) (Розенталь)

> **Неоднородные** определения характеризуют предмет **с разных сторон**, в разных отношениях, т. е. выражают признаки, относящиеся к разным родовым (общим) понятиям: *В углу гостиной стояло **пузатое ореховое** бюро* (Г.) — форма и материал; *Мы жили в подвале **большого каменного** дома* (М. Г.) — размер и материал.

В то же время довольно часто одни и те же определения могут быть и однородными, и неоднородными в зависимости от вкладываемого смысла, от стиля речи. Например:

> Если такие [разные] признаки объединены **общим родовым понятием**, подобные определения могут стать однородными: *Для туристской базы отведён **большой, каменный** дом* (объединяющий признак — ‘благоустроенный’).

Может быть, если в нашем примере ***теплые*** и ***густые*** объединить таким общим понятием, как "оптимальное состояние сливок для использования", то и между ними можно поставить запятую (хотя, скорее, это надуманно и маловероятно).

2. ***Теплый, густой запах смолы наполнял воздух.***

> Согласованные определения являются **однородными**:
>
> 5) если представляют собой **художественные** определения:
>   *Его бледно-голубые, стеклянные глаза разбегались* (Т.);
>   то же при употреблении определения-прилагательного в **переносном значении**:
>   *Тяжёлые, холодные лучи лежали на вершинах окрестных гор* (Л.).

Вот ещё примеры из [справочника Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=109), где тоже говорится об однородности прилагательных, использующихся в переносном значении:

> ***Жестокая, студеная*** весна налившиеся почки убивает (Ахм.); *В сердце **темный, душный** хмель* (Ахм.).

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: @Marina  И Вам спасибо за вопрос! Тема на самом деле вызывает массу сомнений.